# if...else statement runs both parts of the code

Tags: r

I need my code to check a vector to see if any of the values are negative and return an error if one or more are. If none are negative, I need it to find the geometric mean of the values. The problem is when there are negative values my code is giving both the error message and the geometric mean, which I don't want to have happen.

```
gm=function(x){
n=length(x)

    for(i in 1:n){
        if(x[i]<0){
            cat("ERROR: x value is negative")
            break
            }else{
            y=prod(x)^(1/n)
        }
    }
y
}
gm(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid looping through a vector and checking a condition. Instead, you could use `any` to check if the condition holds for any of the elements of the vector:

```
gm <- function(x) {
  if (any(x < 0)) {
    stop("x contains a negative element")
  } else {
    prod(x)^(1/length(x))
  }
}
```

You can see it in action:

```
gm(c(4, 16))
# [1] 8
gm(c(-4, 16))
# Error in gm(c(-4, 16)) : x contains a negative element
```